# Aurelia/Typescript - Refresh page after Upload

Tags: typescript, asp.net-web-api, aurelia

I have some calls in my `public run()` method that retrieve some information via an API call. This happens when the page loads.

However, once loaded the user will perform an upload. After the upload is complete I would like to refresh the page with the info the `public run()` pulls - Which at this point should contain new info based on the upload happening.

I tried adding a `this.run()` to the end of the upload, but it doesn't seem to work. I basically just want this thing to refresh (postback) after the upload.

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

```
    public run(): void {


    try {
        this._apiBureauModHistory.GetTopBureauModUpdateHistory().then(x => {
            if (x) {
                this.bmuh = x;     
                switch (this.bmuh.Bureau) {
                    case "00":
                        this.bmuh.Bureau = "Ncci";
                        break;
                    case "04":
                        this.bmuh.Bureau = "CA";
                        break;
                    case "31":
                        this.bmuh.Bureau = "NY";
                        break;
                    case "37":
                        this.bmuh.Bureau = "PA";
                        break;
                    case "07":
                        this.bmuh.Bureau = "DE";
                        break;
                    case "48":
                        this.bmuh.Bureau = "WI";
                        break;
                    case "21":
                        this.bmuh.Bureau = "MI";

                    case "22":
                        this.bmuh.Bureau = "MN";

                }
            }

        })
    }
    catch (e) {
        this.running = false;
        this.runError = e;
    }

    try {
        this._apiBureauModHistory.GetAllBureauModUpdateHistory().then(x => {
            if (x) {

                this.bmuh_arr = x;  
               // this.bmuh_arr.forEach(function (t) { if (!this.bmuh_summ.includes(t.UploadedDate)) this.bmuh_summ.push(t.UploadedDate); });
                for (var i = 0; i < this.bmuh_arr.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = i + 1; j < this.bmuh_arr.length; j++){
                        if (this.bmuh_arr[i].UploadedDate === this.bmuh_arr[j].UploadedDate)
                            j = ++i;
                           // this.bmuh_summ.push(this.bmuh_arr[i].UploadedDate); 
                    }

                }
            }
        })
    }
    catch (e) {
        this.running = false;
        this.runError = e;
    }
}


upload(): void {
    var formData = new FormData()
    for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        formData.append('files', this.files[i]);
    }

    this.http.fetch(window.wcApiUrl + '/Lookup/BureauModUpdate/CreateBureauModUpdates', {
        method: 'post',
        body: formData
    })

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you used to call `this.run()` from the `upload()` method? Did you use `.then()`?

Answer (score 0):

In the `upload()` function you have a `fetch` statement. This should return a promise that resolves or rejects. You could use .then() like so:

```
this.http.fetch(window.wcApiUrl + 
'/Lookup/BureauModUpdate/CreateBureauModUpdates', {
    method: 'post',
    body: formData
})
.then(response =>{
   //do something with response.json()
   this.updateInfo(response.json());
})
.catch(err=>console.log('something error-ed : %o',err);
```

You could for example return from the post the info you need as JSON and use that. (`fetch' by the way is asynchronous, so code after`fetch` will run before the respons is returned.)

You could even refresh the page, but that would defeat the purpose of the single page application pattern.